# How to create a PostgreSQL function that I can call from DBeaver?

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions

Here is the sample date:

```
CREATE TABLE #logins (
    username text not null,
    logged_at timestamp not null);  
insert into #logins (username, logged_at) values
    ('a','2019-01-01'),('b','2019-01-01'),('c','2019-01-01'),('d','2019-01-01'),('e','2019-01-01'),        
    ('a','2019-02-01'),('b','2019-02-01'),('c','2019-02-01'),('f','2019-02-01'),('g','2019-02-01'),
    ('h','2019-02-01'),('i','2019-02-01'),('j','2019-02-01'),('a','2019-03-01'),('b','2019-03-01'),
    ('f','2019-03-01'),('h','2019-03-01'),('g','2019-03-01'),('k','2019-03-01'),('l','2019-03-01'),
    ('m','2019-03-01'),('n','2019-03-01'),('o','2019-03-01'),('a','2019-04-01'),('f','2019-04-01'),   
    ('g','2019-04-01'),('k','2019-04-01'),('l','2019-04-01')`
```

What I normally do

```
drop table if exists #a;
create table #a as 
select username, min(logged_at) as date from #logins --Please note that there is **MIN()** here 
group by 1;


alter table #a 
add m_1 varchar;
update #a
set m_1 = (select username from #logins 
            where add_months(#a.date,1) = #logins.logged_at and #logins.username = #a.username);

alter table #a 
add m_2 varchar;
update #a
set m_2 = (select username from #logins 
            where add_months(#a.date,2) = #logins.logged_at and #logins.username = #a.username);

alter table #a 
add m_3 varchar;
update #a
set m_3 = (select username from #logins 
            where add_months(#a.date,1) = #logins.logged_at and #logins.username = #a.username);

select to_date(date,'yyyy-mm') as date, count(username) as num_acc,
                                    count(m_1) as m_1,
                                    count(m_2) as m_2,
                                    count(m_3) as m_3
from #a
group by 1
order by 1
```

The expected result:

```
             num_acc   m_1     m_2     m_3
2019-01-01      5       3       2       3
2019-02-01      5       3       2       3
2019-03-01      5       2       0       2
```

From this point I will download the data and visualize it in cohort

The point is that I want to create a function for convenient. I am working on Dbeaver using PostgreSQL for your information.
In this function, we only need to input a table with ID and Date then it would automate the process.

This is my try so far:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(timestamp,varchar(255)) 
    RETURNS int 
declare
    counter integer :=1
stable 
AS $$

   LOOP 
      EXIT WHEN counter = 6 ; 
      counter := counter + 1 ; 
      alter table #a
      add counter varchar;
     update #a
     counter = select user_name from #logins 
                where add_month(#logins.logged_at,counter) = #a.first_login 
                #a.first_login and #logins.username = #a.username
   END LOOP 

$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

This is embarrassing as `function` in SQL is quite difficult. This is the best I could do.

(p/s: please sympathy that `LANGUAGE plpythonu` can not be used. Our only option is `sql`)

Comment: You can't be using Postgres as it won't allow a table like `#logins`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  yes it required a specific schema, this case is an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Revised: Incorporating additional requirement**

Well with the new information a small adjustment can be made. Since "No matter how many times you login within a month, we only count 1, based on the username".  Rather than looking for equal dates we'll use the Posrgres date_trunc function to look at the 1st of the month whatever the actual login date happens to be. Also continuing to use WHERE EXISTS ensures that no matter how many logins a user has we only count 1. So the **REVISED** function:

```
create or replace function collect_user_login_counts(login_start_in date) 
 returns table( "Date"   text
              , num_acc  bigint
              , m_1      bigint 
              , m_2      bigint 
              , m_3      bigint
              )               
 language sql strict
as $$
    -- work table exists for single execution so clear any existing data
    truncate user_login_wrk;

    with su_dater as
      -- get each user and the earliest date of login such that the login date in not less than parameter date 
          (select l0.username, min(date_trunc('month', l0.logged_at))::date logged_at
             from logins l0
            where date_trunc('month', l0.logged_at)::date >= date_trunc('month', login_start_in)::date
            group by l0.username
          )
       , inserter as 
         -- insert the the counter table the user name for least login date and the following 3 months, 
         -- return each row for subsequent summerization  
         ( insert into user_login_wrk(username, logged_at, m_1,m_2,m_3)
             select su.username
                  , su.logged_at
                  , (select su.username where exists 
                                        (select null 
                                           from logins l1 
                                          where l1.username = su.username 
                                            and date_trunc('month',l1.logged_at)::date = (su.logged_at + interval '1 month')::date))
                  , (select su.username where exists 
                                        (select null 
                                           from logins l2 
                                          where l2.username = su.username 
                                            and date_trunc('month',l2.logged_at)::date = (su.logged_at + interval '2 month')::date))
                  , (select su.username where exists 
                                        (select null 
                                           from logins l3
                                          where l3.username = su.username 
                                            and date_trunc('month',l3.logged_at)::date = (su.logged_at + interval '3 month')::date))                                              

              from su_dater su  
          returning * 
         )
    -- summarize count on user logins over period current and next 3 months result returned caller         
    select to_char(ulc.logged_at,'yyyy-mm')  
         , count(ulc.username)  
         , count(ulc.m_1)  
         , count(ulc.m_2)  
         , count(ulc.m_3) 
      from  inserter ulc
      where ulc.logged_at >= date_trunc('month',login_start_in)::date
      group by to_char(logged_at,'yyyy-mm')
      order by to_char(logged_at,'yyyy-mm'); 
$$;
```

Testing: 
For testing I changed your original date so that there are no rows actually having the 1st of the month and none on the same day number. Further the parameter date for the function does not occur in the data.

```
truncate logins;
insert into logins (username, logged_at) values
        ('a','2019-01-03'),('b','2019-01-04'),('c','2019-01-11'),('d','2019-01-15'),('e','2019-01-21'),        
        ('a','2019-02-06'),('b','2019-02-02'),('c','2019-02-04'),('f','2019-02-08'),('g','2019-02-09'),
        ('h','2019-02-12'),('i','2019-02-24'),('j','2019-02-26'),('a','2019-03-02'),('b','2019-03-03'),
        ('f','2019-03-05'),('h','2019-03-11'),('g','2019-03-17'),('k','2019-03-31'),('l','2019-03-09'),
        ('m','2019-03-29'),('n','2019-03-27'),('o','2019-03-24'),('a','2019-04-06'),('f','2019-04-03'),   
        ('g','2019-04-14'),('k','2019-04-30'),('l','2019-04-11'); 
select collect_user_login_counts(date '2019-01-18');        -- select as row
select * from collect_user_login_counts(date '2019-01-18'); -- select as individual columns
```

**RESULTS**

```
Date    | num_acc| m_1| m_2| m_3
________________________________
2019-01 | 5      | 3  | 2  | 1
2019-02 | 5      | 3  | 2  | 0
2019-03 | 5      | 2  | 0  | 0
```

Despite the data changes the same results are produced. 
BTW. I did test the original with your data. And those results matched your expectations exactly except for m_3, which is explained in original reply. I just did not post it, my error.

*Original reply**  
Well there are a couple issues with your code as posted. As @a_horse_with_no_name pointed out the # character not valid
in a Postgres object name, unless the name is double quote enclosed (i.e. "#logins") regardless of the schema. Additionally Postges does not have the function add_months (you could have it as a user written function, but I cannot
know that.)  
I notice a couple inconsistencies  with your expected results. First the final query in what you "normally do" cannot produce those results. The query returns year-month for the date, The expected has year-month-day. I'll assume year-month. Secondly the m_3 expected output is, I believe, incorrect. This is due to the set m_3 where you uses add_months(#a.date,1). I believe from the naming structure and prior settings, this is a copy/past typo that should read
add_months(#a.date,3). I will assume it's the latter. That does however change the results for column m_3.  
  
 
There is an item in your posted function I haven't fully understood. I not sure of the magic number 6 is doing. Were you attempting to create columns m_1 thru m_6, that would seem to be. However the code would actually try to create the
column name counter 6 times, that would fail on the 2nd one. In the function below I'll stay with m_1 thru m_3. If m_6 is your goal, just replicate m_1 editing as needed. (also have to update table definition).
  
Some Changes Made:

1. I do not name columns date. Its a reserved word and while you can get away with it now, that could change at any time. So I'll use logged_at in the work table.
2. I dislike single character names for DB objects So #a becomes user_login_wrk.
3. I avoid DML (create,alter) in functions. So the table is created externally. Besides for a SQL function it must exist
   initially unless the entire function is dynamic SQL and a single string.

Taking all that into consideration we get:

```
-- create 'months' work table
create table user_login_wrk( username  text
                           , logged_at date
                           , m_1       text
                           , m_2       text
                           , m_3       text
                           );
```

Now for the main event.

```
create or replace function collect_user_login_counts(login_start_in date) 
 returns table( "Date"   text
              , num_acc  bigint
              , m_1      bigint 
              , m_2      bigint 
              , m_3      bigint
              )               
 language sql strict
as $$
    -- work table exists for single execution so clear any existing data
    truncate user_login_wrk;

    with su_dater as
          -- get each user and the earliest date of login such that the login date in not less than parameter date 
          (select l0.username, min(l0.logged_at)::date logged_at
             from logins l0
            where l0.logged_at::date >= login_start_in
            group by l0.username
          )
       , inserter as 
         -- insert the the counter table the user name for least login date and the following 3 months, 
         -- return each row for subsequent summerization  
         ( insert into user_login_wrk(username, logged_at, m_1,m_2,m_3)
             select su.username
                  , su.logged_at
                  , (select su.username where exists (select null from logins l1 where l1.username = su.username and l1.logged_at = su.logged_at + interval '1 month')) 
                  , (select su.username where exists (select null from logins l2 where l2.username = su.username and l2.logged_at = su.logged_at + interval '2 month'))
                  , (select su.username where exists (select null from logins l3 where l3.username = su.username and l3.logged_at = su.logged_at + interval '3 month'))    
               from su_dater su  
          returning * 
         )
    -- summerize count on user logins over period current and next 3 months result returned caller         
    select to_char(ulc.logged_at,'yyyy-mm')  
         , count(ulc.username)  
         , count(ulc.m_1)  
         , count(ulc.m_2)  
         , count(ulc.m_3) 
      from  inserter ulc
      where ulc.logged_at >= login_start_in
      group by to_char(logged_at,'yyyy-mm')
      order by to_char(logged_at,'yyyy-mm'); 
$$;
-- test
select collect_user_login_counts(date '2019-01-01');        -- select as row
select * from collect_user_login_counts(date '2019-01-01'); -- select as individual columns
select * from collect_user_login_counts(date '2019-02-01'); -- Next month
```

The above completely refreshes the work table and rebuilds it. However, there are times when viewing the results for the last run is desirable/needed. The following provides that capability. (Note the actual query can be extracted and run stand alone if desired.

```
create or replace function show_user_login_counts()
 returns table( "Date"   text
              , num_acc  bigint
              , m_1      bigint 
              , m_2      bigint 
              , m_3      bigint
              )               
 language sql strict
as $$    
    select to_char(ulc.logged_at,'yyyy-mm')  
         , count(ulc.username)  
         , count(ulc.m_1)  
         , count(ulc.m_2)  
         , count(ulc.m_3) 
     from user_login_wrk ulc
    group by to_char(logged_at,'yyyy-mm')
    order by to_char(logged_at,'yyyy-mm')  ; 
$$;
-- test
select show_user_login_counts();        -- select as row
select * from show_user_login_counts(); -- select as individual columns
```

There are a couple issues not addressed. Currently each subsequent (m_1,m_2,m_3) is exact months from the start date?What happens if a user login is not the exact date but the next day? Also there is no allowance for a user logging in
multiple times in a month. Well those are questions for another day.

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer @Belayer, and sorry for not being specifically detail in the question. I would like to answer that from my expected result, rows are specific months (1), values of num_acc column are number of entry in (1). And values of m_1, m_2 columns are number of entry in (1) + 1 month, +2 month, + 3 month

Comment: No matter how many times you login within a month, we only count 1, based on the username.

Comment: Totally, appreciate your efforts, however, It would be useful if you could test it on my sample data